# Top 2 Columns and Top 1 Row From Pandas Table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, slice

I have a Pandas cross tab table that looks like the following:

[image]

I want to trim the data frame, so I only have the top 2 columns of data (Class A and Class B) and the top 1 row of data (True). This is calculated by using the All columns and row. I am excluding the All records in the calculation. This is a dummy example for something I am trying to do on a larger dataset which is why I don't want to hard coded solution to this dummy example.

I am hoping for the dataframe to look like the following:

```
TFColumn Class A  Class B All
================================
    True 97120    49035   196590
     All 148026   74978   300000
```

I've successfully done this for the rows, but I'm not sure how to extend this to the columns.

```
contingencyTable.sort_values(by=['All'], ascending = False).head(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also [`pd.DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html); maybe something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Class A": [50906, 97120, 148026],
    "Class B": [25943, 49035, 74978],
    "Class C": [17813, 33805, 51618],
    "Class D": [8784, 16630, 25378],
    "All": [103410, 196590, 300000]
}, index=["False", "True", "All"])

rows = df.nlargest(n=2, columns="All").index
cols = df.T.nlargest(n=3, columns="All").index

out = df.loc[rows, cols]
```

out:

```
         All  Class A  Class B
All   300000   148026    74978
True  196590    97120    49035
```